# Смазывается контент на сайте

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Почему-то в одной из форм происходит смазывание контента. Пример на скриншотах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В другой же форме все нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Адрес сайта: wolken.ru

Comment: Сам код в студию пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в нормальном виде это лечится вот так:

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.element {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

То есть нужен родительский блок, у которого выставлено `preserve-3d`. В вашем случае нужно переверстать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант это может произойти из-за того, как центрируется этот попапчик. Например:

```
.popup {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 399px;
    height: 499px;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

`translate3d` врубит субпиксельный сдвиг блока. Чтобы этого избежать, убедитесь, что все размеры четко делятся на `2`, в отличии от `399` и `499`.